# Is it possible to retain same session id with BDD in different step files

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cypress

I want to implement BDD with Cypress and want to retain same session id within different step files.

So i have different step files for different feature files.

My feature files look like

1.Login-Login to application

2.Add Employee-Add employee after logging in.

I want to use the same login credentials in step definitions for feature file.

But the problem is cypress clears all cookies within different tests.

So how to achieve this dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Cypress plug-in `cypress-localstorage-commands` you can use to preserve the value of a variable, which can then be used across tests.
You can use it like this:

```
let SESSION_ID = '';
before(() => {
        cy.setLocalStorage('sessionId', '000'); // capture the id for example
        cy.saveLocalStorage()
});

beforeEach(() => {
        cy.restoreLocalStorage();
        cy.getLocalStorage('sessionId').as('id'); 
        SESSION_ID = id;
});

it('test 1', () => {
 cy.get(SESSION_ID).should('eq', '000');
});

it('test 2', () => {
 cy.log(SESSION_ID);
});
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands

The other option is maybe use the fixture files and the command `cy.writeFile` to save the **session id** under the `before` and then capture it under your tests `it`

Comment: Does it works the same way for cypress with bdd also

Comment: I'm actually having difficulty understanding the main problem statement. Would you be able to share the code or something? Using the `cy.writeFile` and storing it into a fixture file would work regardless if BDD or TDD is used.

Comment: Hello ebanster,
Can you please explain in little detail how cy.write can be used.
Right now i have put all BDD steps in one scenario since the session was getting expired if i seggregate the steps under two scenario headings.

Comment: pass the ID or whatever you need to capture as variable. `var varA = <id/token>` then `cy.writeFile('path/to/message.txt', varA)` then 
once it is save to the specified file, you can then capture it via `cy.readFile('path/to/message.txt').then((text) => {
  expect(text).to.equal(<id/token>) // true
})`